# HttpsURLConnection getting 504 error frequently

Tags: java, java-8

Iam using HttpsURLconnection in Java-1.8 and posting to an URL with some parameters. Many times am getting 200 success response but some times am getting 504 gateway timeout error.

Iam struggling with this error for a long time. Any guidance will be greatly helpful. Below is the code am using.

```
public static void sendPostRequest(String url, ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
        ResourceResponse resourceResponse)
{ 
    String token_response = "";

                String grant_password = PrefsPropsUtil.getString("grant.type");
                String client_id = PrefsPropsUtil.getString("client.id");
                String user_name = PrefsPropsUtil.getString("user.name");
                String client_secret = PrefsPropsUtil.getString("client.secret");
                PrintWriter out = resourceResponse.getWriter();
                URL obj = new URL(url);

                System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes", "");
                System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
               //add request header
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
              //  con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                String urlParameters = "grant_type=" + grant_password + "&client_id=" + client_id + "&username=&client_secret=" + client_secret;
                // Send post request
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                con.disconnect();
                //print result
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                out.println(response);

}
```

In the above code I don't know where Iam doing mistake, please correct me on it.

Comment: It depends from the url you are calling, not from  mistake of the caller.
Liferay is not the right topic

Comment: As @DanieleBaggio has pointed out, this is a server side error.  It seems that whatever gateway/firewall, is having a problem connection to the upstream server.  Your code has no influence on this.

Comment: Consider having a built-in retry mechanism with an exponential backoff time in your method.  This may overcome randomly sporadic problems on the queried source.  Logging may also show a well defined pattern (e.g. backups occurring at #:## everyday).

Answer (score 1):

`5xx` codes are considered as server errors. Hence, it's most probably not a problem of the requesting side.

> **504 Gateway Timeout:** The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and
>   did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

I'd suggest you check the server for correct proxy settings or stability of upstream servers etc. Not much could be said from the `HttpsURLconnection`, which seems as generic as it could get.